# How can i install tensorflow framework on robot NAO?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nao-robot

I want to install TensorFlow framework in robot NAO , 
How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Great question! The NAO is a linux machine, so technically it might be possible. Unfortunately, the NAO also has a limited amount of computational power... Depending on the plan you have it might be a better idea to set up an external computer that does the heavy computations for you. This all depends on the application you want to build.

If you decide to install tensorflow on Nao: simply try to use SSH (or Putty) to get a console you can use to install tensorflow.

If you decide to use an external server: maybe this program I wrote a long time ago helps you: https://github.com/rmeertens/nao-wit . It is an example of how to send speech to an external server.

Good luck!